# Trying to rotate a straight line end over end around inner circle

Tags: lua

Straight line, one end point intersects circle. I want the line to pivot at its intersection until the other end point intersects the circle this then becomes the next pivot and so on. The animation would show the line "walking" end over end around the inside of the circle. Trying to do this in lua.

Sorry...looked everywhere! But you guys are awesome!
[image]

Comment: What functions are available for drawing circle and line?

Comment: Well I'm using lua inside an app layer so only a stripped down version is available no draw functions whatsoever...proprietary shapes are available as are imported graphics so I can import a PNG of a line. Also the app rotates graphics from their centre so to achieve a pivot at an end point such as a line we pre draw images with 1:2 ratio so one half contains the graphic the other half is empty. So the app still rotates the whole image but it appears as though it's pivoting like a clock hand.

Comment: Ok, I see you have an algorithm and you know Lua.  So, what's the problem to write a code?

Comment: I can't work out how to calculate the x,y coords of where the line will intersect the circle to make the new pivot given any line length and any radius.

Comment: Can you add a picture to make your problem's description more clear?

Comment: So hopefully that picture is helpful...1, 2 & 3 are the successive pivot points...the red line is a potential start position then it pivots from 1. The pink lines represent the new positions so it's only one line. If it works it will make it look like the line is flipping end over end as it traverses the inner circumference. As the line pivots and travels through however many degrees eventually its leading end point will intersect the circle again and that new intersection becomes the new pivot point and so on.

Comment: As the line pivots across the inner circumference the arc degrees it traces must be somehow proportional to it's length and the radius but my thinking hits a wall there

Comment: `x = 2 * math.asin(line_length/(2 * radius)) * 180 / math.pi`  Pivoting angle = `180-x`

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what that value is telling me? If I have a line length of 156 and radius=118 I get 97.245 but how does that help me calculate the point of intersection?

Comment: What I actually need are x,y coordinates of the intersection. As the app only rotates image objects around their centre after the first rotation the line's rotation point will be in the wrong place so I'll have to use two lines superimposed I think...! This is getting very messy...!

Comment: `I'm not sure what that value is telling me?` (180-x) is the angle between 12 and 23 (on your picture)

Comment: N-th point of intersection is `R*cos(N*x*pi/180), R*sin(N*x*pi/180)`

Comment: Still not getting it. Could you draw a picture of what your maths should look like in relation to the line and circle?

Comment: New picture. Rt is fixed point of rotation so after first rotation line will need to be flipped/inversed. I1...I2...IN are intersection points. So my program needs to know how much to rotate by until intersection. Is your N-th point an index I can increment?

Comment: `how much to rotate by until intersection` - angle F-Rt-FI1 equals to (180-x)

Comment: I used 512 as line length and 256 as radius and get (180-x)=0

Comment: Of course, the line of length 512 has no room to be rotated inside a circle of diameter 512

Comment: Yep sorry I'm being more Stupid than usual. Also forgot the image is 512 but the only portion drawn as a line is 256... So I just have to figure out how to iterate the pivot angle values overlay a new line with its rotation point the opposite end hide the previous line then loop. Thank you very much Egor. Wish it came that easy to me!

Comment: I think we can mark this as answered.

Comment: Do you mind if I credit you?